# Page update when clicking a button (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I want to render page again, after clicking a button. How can I accomplish it? In particular how would you change my program to generate random texts, when clicking the button?

```
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']; 
var Hello = React.createClass({   
    randomText(color) { 
        var style = {
            color: colors[color],
        }
        return ( <h1 style={style}>  Random text  </h1> ); 
    }, 
    randomNumberOfRandomText() { 
        var color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
        var rows = []; 
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            rows.push(this.randomText(color));
        }
        return <div> {rows} </div>; 
    }, 
    handleSubmit() { 

    }, 
    render: function() {
        return  ( <div>  
            <section>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Generate new random texts! </button>
            </section>
        {this.randomNumberOfRandomText()} 
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/rvLow09s/

Note that we don't want to see the previous elements in the page.

Comment: Hi, __handleSubmit())__ contain nothing ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most circumstances, Jean's answer is the best proper way to update your component's data. With that said, the code below accomplishes what you want as well.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rvLow09s/1/)

The reason I'm including it is because the **forceUpdate()** can be useful in cases like yours where the data that is updating in your component is the result of a psuedorandom generator. Since your priority is simulating random behavior over updating component state or prop data, **forceUpdate()** can be a cleaner way to make this particular update re-render itself.

From [React's Component API Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate):

> If your render() method reads from something other than this.props or this.state, you'll need to tell React when it needs to re-run render() by calling forceUpdate().

```
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']; 
var Hello = React.createClass({   
    randomText(color) { 
        var style = {
            color: colors[color],
        }
        return ( <h1 style={style}>  Random text  </h1> ); 
    }, 
    randomNumberOfRandomText() { 
        var color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
        var rows = []; 
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            rows.push(this.randomText(color));
        }
        return <div> {rows} </div>; 
    }, 
    handleSubmit(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 
    render: function() {
        return  ( <div>  
            <section>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Generate new random texts! </button>
            </section>
        {this.randomNumberOfRandomText()} 
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: I actually think your answer is better.  In most cases, you want as little amount of state as possible.  There is no reason to keep this randomly generated text as state when you could just call `forceUpdate()` to re-render the component with new randomly generated text.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, why not use **setState** and **getInitialState**.

```
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']; 
var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            text: []
        }
    },

    randomText(color) { 
        var style = {
            color: colors[color],
        }
        return ( <h1 style={style}>  Random text  </h1> ); 
    }, 
    randomNumberOfRandomText() { 
        var color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
        var rows = []; 
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            rows.push(this.randomText(color));
        }
        this.setState({text: rows});
    }, 
    handleSubmit() { 
        this.randomNumberOfRandomText();
    }, 
    render: function() {
        return  ( <div>  
            <section>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Generate new random texts! </button>
        </section>
        <div>{this.state.text}</div> 
       </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I update [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0wkL132/).

When you click on **handleSubmit()**, you execute **randomNumberOfRandomText()** whish update the state of element.

> setState() will always trigger a re-render

Comment: Cool! I didn't know the last statement: "setState() will always trigger a re-render".

Comment: Because when you call __setState()__, this method execute __render__ component method. Sorry, I should have specified the react doc !